# QHttpMultiPart POST returns error 500

Tags: qt, cgi, multipartform-data

I'm experimenting with multi-part form submissions for the purpose of uploading files to a web server.  I adapted the following code from the sample found in the documentation for QHttpMultiPart:

```
QHttpMultiPart * pMultiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

QHttpPart textPart1;
textPart1.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, "form-data; name=\"Sport1\"");
textPart1.setBody("Dodgeball");
pMultiPart->append(textPart1);

QHttpPart textPart2;
textPart2.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, "form-data; name=\"Sport2\"");
textPart2.setBody("Kickball");
pMultiPart->append(textPart2);

QNetworkRequest request(myUrl);
QNetworkReply * pReply = m_pNetworkManager->post(request, pMultiPart);
pMultiPart->setParent(pReply);
connect(pReply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(replyFinished()));
```

The server keeps rejecting the submission with error 500.  The problem is definitely not the script that is receiving the data as I have reduced it to simply return "Hello World" no matter what the request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Qt (version 5.5) is doing something wrong with the boundary.  I was able to get it to work by both setting the boundary to a string of my own choosing and by setting the header which specifies the boundary.

I added these two lines:

```
pMultiPart->setBoundary("---------------------jasglfuyqwreltjaslgjlkdaghflsdgh");
...
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + pMultiPart->boundary());
```

Here it is all together:

```
QHttpMultiPart * pMultiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
pMultiPart->setBoundary("---------------------jasglfuyqwreltjaslgjlkdaghflsdgh");

QHttpPart textPart1;
textPart1.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, "form-data; name=\"Sport1\"");
textPart1.setBody("Dodgeball");
pMultiPart->append(textPart1);

QHttpPart textPart2;
textPart2.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, "form-data; name=\"Sport2\"");
textPart2.setBody("Kickball");
pMultiPart->append(textPart2);

QNetworkRequest request(myUrl);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + pMultiPart->boundary());
QNetworkReply * pReply = m_pNetworkManager->post(request, pMultiPart);
pMultiPart->setParent(pReply);
connect(pReply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(replyFinished()));
```

Comment: I lost about 4 hours on the same issue today before finding this (correct) answer. The spec requires the boundary to be specified in the header, and Qt does not do that by default. Thanks mjk!

Comment: Actually Qt doesn't set the boundary IF you manually set a valid header. In which case you have to include it manually. If you don't set a header, boundary is included.